# PostgreSQL local time

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone

Is there a better way to get local time to the second in PostgreSQL than this?

```
Set timezone= 'America/New_York';
Select to_char(current_timestamp, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') As EasternCurrentTime;
```

We do a lot of these in different places for logging within our ETL and would like to do it on one line.

Comment: You could abstract it into a postgres function so at least its just a one-liner and compartmentalized to the current thread/query

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest

```
SELECT to_char(current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York',
               'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that (though I think we're not supposed to post these)

Comment: Nobody will complain as long as you don't write it as an answer. The preferred way to express thanks is upvoting and/or accepting the answer.